# HTML multiple file upload not uploading properly

Tags: html

I have 15 different multiple file upload inputs. When I upload 1 image each of the input type the result is good. but when i try to upload 2 images per input type the result will only show the first 10 input type's images

below are my input fields

```
<input type="file" name="1[]" class="form-control"  multiple>

<input type="file" name="2[]" class="form-control"  multiple>

<input type="file" name="3[]" class="form-control"  multiple>
```

up to

```
<input type="file" name="15[]" class="form-control"  multiple>
```

i already adjusted the following in my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 505M
```

Comment: Please *please* read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines, and take the [tour]; as written we can only make guesses, which is a waste of our time and yours. You need to give us information, show us the code, explain where the problem occurs; is it after 10 files or is it after number of uploads hit an upload limit?

Comment: sorry will edit the question now.

Comment: Who wants to bet that the problem is (a) Due to the server side code and (b) Is due to the total file size being uploaded and not the number of files?

Comment: @Quentin how can i adjust the total file size being uploaded?

Comment: Upload files with smaller file sizes.

Comment: @Quentin i already adjusted my php.ini upload_max_filesize = 500M and post_max_size = 505M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOlVED!

here is the solution, in your php.ini add the following.

```
max_file_uploads = 200
```